# Relation between Claw-free permutation and Trapdoor

Tags: trapdoor

Can someone explain the two definitions in relation to each other?

Is a claw-free permutation a permutation without a trapdoor?

---

For your convenience, here's the definition of a "[claw-free permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw-free_permutation)":

> Let $f_1,f_2$ be permutations. A triple $(x,y,z)$ is called a *claw* iff $f_1(x)=f_2(x)=z$. A pair $f_1,f_2$ of permutations is called *claw-free* iff there exists no efficient algorithm that can find a claw for these permutations.

The definition of a [trapdoor permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapdoor_function) is a bit lengthier and thus only given as a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "**a** claw-free permutation", given that the definitions only ever talks about pairs. Does that mean a function that is claw-free with every function but itself?